# Blighttown or Great Wolf Sif?

Tags: dark-souls

Ok, I'm recently started to play Dark Souls my first time. I am playing as a Pyromancer with Hollow-Shield and Rapier+7. I am about SL 25 or so... So I fought me trough the Depth and killed the Gaping Dragon, and got the Key to Blighttown. I don't like Blighttown really much: Dark, Green and Toxic! So I headed to Darkroot-Garden and Basin. I killed the Hydra and the Moonlight Butterfly (in my opinion the easiest Boss so far) and I came to Sif. Sif really annoys me; he's fast, deals a ton of Damage and he's tanky too. After several trys I thought: "Maybe it's better to go to Blighttown before and come back later".

Now, should I go to Blighttown or is this place harder than Sif and I have to farm and Level-up some more, before? Hope for a fast reply! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haha, Blightdown is definitely the worst. Sif is actually pretty easy - get under him and attack his belly.

Comment: Oh, and if you're frustrated now just wait until you get to Anor Londo XD

Comment: I have people on my friends list who have done "zero" soul level runs (i.e. no leveling/cashing in souls) so take heart! every boss is killable at any level if you study them and have patience. However, if you are tanking and having issues, try removing armor/reducing weight. This will preserve stamina and increase slightly the "invincibility" frames (dodge rolling etc). Check also your framerate, can't recall if it is DS 1 or 2 or both, but over 30fps can increase durability loss and reduce parry ability (?)

Comment: @Yorik it was DkS 2 that the framerate was an issue in regards to weapon durability, specifically because the weapons were a lot more fragile, (i.e. lower durablity) and sustaining higher durablity loss due to the framerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that these are two very different challenges - One is a hard and fast challenge, the other is more of a treacherous marathon. Considering you're going to have to tackle both at some point anyway, the best thing to do is give some advice on *how* to tackle these challenges.

### Sif

- Fire: Sif is weak to fire, so get some Pyromancies or some Charcoal Resin.
- Movement: Sif has a very specific moveset. The big moves you need to look out for are:

  - Charge-Swing: He does this move when he has some distance on you. The best option here is to block
  - Double-Side Swing to Overhead: He uses this at mid-close range. This is very easily avoided with timing. Roll as he begins the swing, and you should avoid getting hit by the I-Frames granted by rolling.
  - The double "Whirlwind" Swing: This is the killer. Again, he uses this at mid-close range. Without a shield with a high enough stability, and a *huge* stamina bar, blocking is not going to work. Again, rolling toward him is the key. Try rolling just after he begins the swing, and again after a .5 second delay.
- **Stay under him**. Don't use the auto-lock targeting, that's only going to confuse you. If you stay under him, and attack the legs, you can avoid most of the stress of dodging constantly.
- After his health drops to below 20%, he starts to limp around, so his movement is well reduced, but his moveset still stays the same

### Blighttown

- **Use the Spider Shield!** This shield is incredibly handy down here, especially with the Toxic-Dart shooting little buggers hidden around the place. The shield completely negates any poison or toxic effect attacks. **Stay in turtle mode!**
- Take it easy, watch and listen. It's dark, and confusing, and enemies are hidden around every corner. Don't get frustrated and try and run ahead - you will get ganked *so fast*
- A bow comes in hand a lot down here. Taking our an enemy from range is very useful, or even just pulling enemies to deal with them one-on-one.
- Slow and steady wins the race!
- I would also suggest watching some Blighttown walkthrough videos for this, you can find some neat loot, and learn your way around.

**Remember - Persistence is the key!**

Comment: First: Thanks for this great Answer! Second: I'll go to Blighttown, uprgade my Flame a little bit and come back to kill Sif! "Your days are numbered!" :-)